# how to resolve ubercart checkout IE Issue?

Tags: ubercart

I am using Drupal 6. While checking out with IE 7 or 8, users get stuck in a loop; when they click on

[image]

they are redirect to

[image]

When users click on the submit button, they are again redirected to the review order page, as in the first image.
When I searched on drupal.org, I found a "fix in Ubercart Webform Checkout Pane" module, but I am not using it.

It is working fine on Firefox and Google Chrome.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by blocking java-script (some java-script file) on page.tpl for this page and found this is working.
the issue was i am using fancy box for my site which was loaded on all pages, and ubercart already have this so there was conflict in java-script.